# Using mutliprocessing.connection module, not able to talk to 'other' machines?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I have wrapped the Listener and Client function in a program to send and receive information between client and server.  It works fine when address is ('localhost', 6000) OR
('ip_of_localhost', 6000).  Where ip_of_localhost is some xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa normal specification.  However, when I try to communicate across the net it fails and says they machine refused connection.  I realize this could be some other blocking element, firewalls rules, router configuration, or such.  I am not asking here if this is the case.   But rather is there anything in the below code that is erroneous for doing the task?  Did I miss something?

```
def readpipe(addr, phase=False):
    """
    Get data from a pipe ... matlab or python can send it ...
    """

    headers = None
    matrix = None
    name = None
    address = addr
    print "Address {}".format(address)
    listener = Listener(address, authkey='secret password')
    conn = listener.accept()
    print 'Connection accepted from ', listener.last_accepted
    count = 0
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv()
        count +=1
#        print "msg {}\n{}".format(count, msg)
        if name == None:
            name = msg
        elif headers == None:
            headers = msg
        elif matrix == None:
            matrix = msg
        if msg == 'close':
            conn.close()
            break
    listener.close()

    if headers[0] != 'Frequency':
        headers[0] = 'Frequency'
        print "Column 0 should be Frequncy for TestEVAL to know the X axis"

    data = matrix_to_dict(matrix, headers)
    return data, headers, name


def writepipe(address, headers, data, name, phase=False):
    """
    Write dataset to a pipe ...
    """

    conn = Client(address, authkey='secret password')
    conn.send(name)
    conn.send(headers)
    conn.send(data)
    conn.send('close')
    conn.close()
```

Comment: There's no difference in the code between dealing with localhost and dealing with an external system. You're most likely dealing with a firewall issue.

Comment: Yeah == that is my suspicion as well.  However, I wanted to know if the code listed is in error.   That it works for localhost seems to imply no.  Note: when I tried on a remote host I used hosts on the same subnet only separated by a switch.  So either the hosts have blocks or the switch does.  Somewhat surprised network security would implement a block at the switch.

Comment: I think I need a clarification.  When a connection address is defined (provided to the method) as a tuple of (address, number) the number is the internet Port Id being used for the connection to the address and the structure of the address is recognized to be of type AF_INET?  (Address family internet)